# Find Partial matching elements between two dataframe columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames in which I need to match column A of **Input** data frame with **Lookup** data frame and find the partial matching elements. My resulting data frame will be as data frame **Result**.

```
A=c("Green|Red|Yellow","Blue","Orange|Peach","Violet")
B=c(23,41,65,89)
Input=data.frame(A,B)

Matches=c("Green","Orange","Red","Yellow","Peach")
Lookup=data.frame(Matches)

Matched=c("Yes","Yes","Yes","No")
Result=data.frame(A,B,Matched)
```

If someone know the solution pleas help.

Comment: In your Result Blue should be No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do it with an `ifelse`statement:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

Input %>% 
  mutate(Matched = ifelse(str_detect(A, paste(Lookup$Matches, collapse = "|")), "Yes", "No"))
```

```
                 A  B Matched
1 Green|Red|Yellow 23     Yes
2             Blue 41      No
3     Orange|Peach 65     Yes
4           Violet 89      No
```